# How can I send a Json Object with ajax to ODataController

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, odata

I have a OData Service, and I want to send a Json Object to it. But I don't get it!

This is my code:

In the MVC Controller

```
public class SyncController : ODataController
{
 [HttpPost]
  public IQueryable<AppWriteError> GetSync(AppSyncDataModel data)
  {
    // do some stuff
  }
}
```

this is the `AppSyncDataModel`:

```
public class AppSyncDataModel
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(synchData) ,
    success: function () {
        alert("success :-)");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("fail :-(");
    }
```

So if I run this, the `AppSynchDataModel` is always null, and I get the following message:

```
{
  "odata.error":{
    "code":"","message":{
      "lang":"en-US","value":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:3367/odata/Sync'."
    },"innererror":{
      "message":"No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset'.","type":"","stacktrace":""
    }
  }
}
```

How do I have to do it?

Comment: Maybe try changing your url to http://localhost:3367/odata/Sync - looks like a mapping problem. You may also want to add a simple get mapping and just make sure you can hit that from your browser/curl etc.

Comment: And this is my Json "{"UserId":"3d4bd913-ab5e-4d52-984d-6cb4b7eba155"}"

Comment: no defently not, on this address is my OData service runnig, when i'm debugging

Comment: you saw /odata/ instead of just /data/?

Comment: sorry no it's oData. I changed it now... thanks

Comment: Is it possible to send Json Data to OData Controller?